# How to access statistics from YouTube Data API in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, youtube, statistics

I am running a php script that retrieves videos from a YouTube channel using a channelId.

```
$API_key    = 'MY_KEY';
$channelID  = 'MY_CHANNEL_ID';
$maxResults = 2;

$videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));
```

Then I insert it into a webpage with:

```
<iframe width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <h2>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h2>
                        <h2>'. $item->snippet->publishedAt .'</h2>
                        <h2>'. $item->statistics->duration .'</h2>
```

I can't seem to access the statistics part of the json file. when I print the json it looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [kind] => youtube#searchListResponse
    [etag] => "XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/n6hG3LC-2onr- 
    5PwKJtRxnC1Kjc"
    [nextPageToken] => CAEQAA
    [regionCode] => US
    [pageInfo] => stdClass Object
    (
        [totalResults] => 1094
        [resultsPerPage] => 1
    )

    [items] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                [etag] => 
      "XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/lKQ8CNf00_OxqchddzGEYtbidqk"
                [id] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [kind] => youtube#video
                        [videoId] => YxjEmz6KWdU
                    )

                [snippet] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [publishedAt] => 2018-04-06T21:10:48.000Z
                        [channelId] => UCV4xOVpbcV8SdueDCOxLXtQ
                        [title] => SE ACABO :'V
                        [description] => https://www.twitch.tv/fernanfloo.
                        [thumbnails] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [default] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/default.jpg
                                        [width] => 120
                                        [height] => 90
                                    )

                                [medium] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/mqdefault.jpg
                                        [width] => 320
                                        [height] => 180
                                    )

                                [high] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/hqdefault.jpg
                                        [width] => 480
                                        [height] => 360
                                    )

                            )

                        [channelTitle] => Fernanfloo
                        [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

So clearly the json file doesn't contain all the info. I believe it's an issue with the url. It is only creating a json file with some info. I have tried switching the url and different paths to duration.

```
$videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));
```

I am new to the YouTube Data API and my knowledge is spotty. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need modify the API request for add the `statistics` in the `part` parameter.

Also, you're using the "search" option - and, according to its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), it doesn't show the `statistics` value *(which is what you need)*.

Due to this, you have to use the "[videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)" option.

This is the modified API request you can use:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YxjEmz6KWdU&maxResults=2&part=snippet%2Cstatistics&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>
```

The following information was taken from the [YouTube Data API - official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list):

- **id:** Id of the YouTube video you want retrieve the `statistics`.
- **key:** your API key.
- **part:** The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more search resource properties that the API response will include. For this case, I added `snippet` and **`statistics`**.

The statistics of this video will be shown in the `statistics` section of the API response.

This are the results obtanied using the [try-it functionality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2Cstatistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22YxjEmz6KWdU%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A2%7D) and specifying the videoId `YxjEmz6KWdU`:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/4N2LykLhXBiFo79x71IYUazfgdk\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [{
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/Pvuq35nnqnUa3-pETVOKpdemDVU\"",
    "id": "YxjEmz6KWdU",
    "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2018-04-06T21:10:48.000Z",
      "channelId": "UCV4xOVpbcV8SdueDCOxLXtQ",
      "title": "SE ACABO :'V",
      "description": "→ https://www.twitch.tv/fernanfloo",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
        },
        "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
        },
        "standard": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/sddefault.jpg",
          "width": 640,
          "height": 480
        },
        "maxres": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YxjEmz6KWdU/maxresdefault.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720
        }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Fernanfloo",
      "tags": [
        "fernanfloo",
        "fernan",
        "fernan el crack",
        "twitch",
        "fernanfloo twitch",
        "en vivo",
        "en directo",
        "regreso",
        "el regreso de fernanfloo",
        "vlog",
        "blog",
        "2018",
        "pc",
        "fornite",
        "fernanfloo con barba",
        "fernanfllo viejo",
        "lol"
      ],
      "categoryId": "20",
      "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
      "localized": {
        "title": "SE ACABO :'V",
        "description": "→ https://www.twitch.tv/fernanfloo"
      }
    },
    "statistics": {
      "viewCount": "21926458",
      "likeCount": "1371385",
      "dislikeCount": "135852",
      "favoriteCount": "0",
      "commentCount": "303938"
    }
  }]
}
```